# Не могу установить requests в PyCharm

Tags: python, requests, pycharm, install

При попытке  установить модуль `requests` через `File > Settings >PythonInterpreter` , получаю ошибку:

> ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/92/96/144f70b972a9c0eabbd4391ef93ccd49d0f2747f4f6a2a2738e99e5adc65/requests-2.26.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)')))

Внимание, вопрос: мне не нужен перевод на русский язык указанного текста, я ищу способ решить эту проблему.

Comment: Сайт pythonhosted.org заблокирован в России по решению Мосгорсуда уже больше двух лет. Решение проблемы — переехать в другую страну.

Comment: Я не верю, что нет способа обойти эту блокировку. А по каким основаниям блокировка? Чем мотивирует свою позицию суд?

Comment: Тьфу! Даже уйдя в программирование и творчество, нельзя спрятаться от политики!

Comment: Мотивирует тем, что на одном IP-адресе с ним случайно оказался сайт с пиратскими видео. https://habr.com/ru/post/453608/

Answer (score 0):

Эту проблему я решил следующим образом:

pip install requests --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org

И всё получилось.